# XSD choice inside all

Tags: xsd

You can't put choice tag inside the all tag. So, is there any workaround to get this functionallity?
For example, I have`<settings>` tag like:

```
<settings>
    <logging />
    <sending />
    <useonly />
</settings>
```

Or something like

```
<settings>
    <logging />
    <notuseonly />
    <sending />
</settings>
```

So I want to prevent `<useonly>` and `<notuseonly>` showing up together, while the order is not important. And if allowed, in XSD it would look like:

```
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="sending" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="logging" />
    <xs:choice>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref ="useonly" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref ="notuseonly" />
     </xs:choice>
  </xs:all>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check this link: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Needs_choice_inside_all

I summarize for you the solutions proposed:

One solution is to wrap the element that can change inside another:

```
  <xsd:all>
   <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="sending" />
   <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="logging"/>
   <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref ="usetype"/>
  </xsd:all>

 <xsd:element name="usetype">
  <xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:choice>
    <xsd:element ref="useonly"/>
    <xsd:element ref="notuseonly"/>
   </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
```

The other one is to use a substitution group:

```
  <xsd:all>
   <xsd:element ref="sending"/>
   <xsd:element ref="logging"/>
   <xsd:element ref="usetype"/>
  </xsd:all>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:element name="usetype" abstract="true"/>
 <xsd:element name="useonly" substitutionGroup="usetype"> ... </xsd:element>
 <xsd:element name="notuseonly" substitutionGroup="usetype"> ... </xsd:element>
```

Comment: So is the substitutionGroup method exactly the desired behavior (as if xs:choice was inside of xs:all)? If so, why don't they just allow that directly?

Comment: I've been trying to get substitutionGroup to work with php soapClient but can't for the life of me