# "This element is not expected" error: xs:sequence versus xs:all

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have some XML I am writing a validator tool for so our clients can test their sample feeds but I'm pretty new to XSD.  I am to a point where everything validates correctly based on the cookie cutter example so I wanted to throw some other scenarios at it. The first one I came up with was having different orders of elements in the base node.

Example:
I am using the following complexType to validate each transaction node

```
<xs:complexType name="transactionType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="id"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="type"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:float" name="amount"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="description"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="status"/>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="transacted_on" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="transacted_at" type="xs:date"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="posted_on" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="posted_at" type="xs:date"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The following example node is in the correct sequence order and thus validates correctly

```
<transaction>
    <id>20150617-123456</id>
    <type>DEBIT</type>
    <amount>17.44</amount>
    <description>Debit Card: CAFE  06/16/15</description>
    <status>POSTED</status>
    <transacted_on>2015-06-17</transacted_on>
    <posted_on>2015-06-16</posted_on>
</transaction>
```

But I want to be able to have the elements in any order. So something like the following will validate correctly. The idea is that all elements are present and can be in any order.

```
<transactions>
    <transaction>
        <amount>17.44</amount>
        <id>20150617-123456</id>
        <type>DEBIT</type>
        <description>Debit Card: CAFE  06/16/15</description>
        <status>POSTED</status>
        <transacted_on>2015-06-17</transacted_on>
        <posted_on>2015-06-16</posted_on>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <id>20150617-123456</id>
        <type>CREDIT</type>
        <amount>17.44</amount>
        <description>VISA Card: payment</description>
        <status>POSTED</status>
        <transacted_on>2015-06-17</transacted_on>
        <posted_on>2015-06-16</posted_on>
    </transaction>
</transactions>
```

I did some research and was quickly pointed towards using the `xs:all` element which should do exactly what I want. So I changed my schema to use `xs:all` instead of `xs:sequence`.

```
<xs:complexType name="transactionType">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="id"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="type"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:float" name="amount"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="description"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="status"/>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="transacted_on" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="transacted_at" type="xs:date"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="posted_on" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="posted_at" type="xs:date"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

When I run my validation after making this change I still get an error:

> This element is not expected. Expected is ( id ).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML Schema does not allow `xs:choice` to be a child of `xs:all`.

Workarounds:

1. Add a wrapper element around the `xs:choice` elements.
2. Abandon `xs:all` and live with a fixed ordering via `xs:sequence`.

I'd suggest that in practice `xs:sequence` works fine and avoids this problem as well as others that often arise with `xs:all`, including violations of the [Unique Particle Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_Particle_Attribution).

Comment: I actually suspected this as being a cause, but if I remove the `xs:choice` tags I still get the same error for having the elements out of order.

Comment: I think I found another post with the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508147/xsd-choice-inside-all