# XSD all inside choice

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the inverse need from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508147/xsd-choice-inside-all).

I'd like either of the following to be valid:

```xml
<a>
  <b></b>
  <c></c>
</a>
```

```xml
<a>
  <d></d>
  <e></e>
</a>
```

I tried doing a `choice` with two `all` children, but that's invalid.
It looks like I could do a `choice` with two `sequence` children, but I don't want implementers to have to worry about the order of elements.
It also looks like I could use `group`s, but they require `ref` names, and the options for the contents don't have obvious names for their groupings. (If they did I'd have structured the XML that way to begin with.)

I've been working off of the [XSD 1.1 documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/).

I'm trying to have my XSD generated from a data structure (Mostly so I can recycle the annotations etc for documentation), so simplicity is important.

Comment: XSD 1.0 or 1.1?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/) I've been working off of is for XSD 1.1. I'm not sure about the [online validator](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/) I've been using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is technically possible in XSD 1.1, the solution is not very nice...

The solution I've got sticks everything in an `xs:all`, then uses an `xs:assert` (XSD 1.1 only) to provide the rules.

This solution while it does work is difficult to read and maintain, and not compatible with XSD 1.0. I would lean towards the choice(seq(b,c), seq(d,e)) solution you described and put the onus on the implementers to get the order right

[image: XSD represented graphically using Liquid XML Studio]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2019 BETA (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="a">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="b" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="c" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="d" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="e" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:all>
            <xs:assert test="((boolean(b) and boolean(c)) or (boolean(d) and boolean(e))) and not ((boolean(b) and boolean(c)) and (boolean(d) and boolean(e)))" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I'll try some of this out tonight; I think you're right that I'll probably just resort to sequences. (also I looked up Liquid Studio because I was curious about your screenshot, and [wow I guess I'm not buying that after all](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/shop).)